# Nginx alias, root/rewrite not working

Tags: nginx, php

I have a **folder** in a domain that is being forward by a Load Balancer (LB), ex: `http://domain.name/project-qa`, and need to setup nginx to received this request and process it to a Craft CMS instalation.

From what I read, there are some problems with the alias function on nginx, so after a while searching I got to this configuration, using root instead of alias:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html/project/public/;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name domain.name;

    location /project-qa/ {
        root /var/www/html/project/public/;
        rewrite ^/project-qa/(.*)$ /$1 break;
   #    try_files $uri $uri/ /project-qa/index.php;

        location ~ \.php$ {
           rewrite ^/project-qa/(.*)$ /$1 break;
           fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

           include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
           fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }
     }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
  }
}
```

With this I'm currently able to serve static files, but any request that should be directed to the index.php file (for example, `http://domain.name/project-qa/admin`) gives the same `twig_error_runtime` error.

I had this setup in Apache before with Alias and was working (so the rules on the LB are working), but the stack now needs to be in nginx, and I'm having problems setting it up.

The Apache vhost config was:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/project/public/assets"
  ServerName domain.name
  Alias /project-qa /var/www/html/project/public
  <Directory "/var/www/html/project/public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The DocumentRoot was pointing to assets but was never used, since the base domain is never used in this server, only the full `http://domain.name/project-qa` (except for the LB ping to check if the server is online).

Any help welcome.

Comment: Does the Craft CMS use a front-controller pattern? How was it configured in Apache?

Comment: I've added the Apache config to the main post.

Yes, all the requests go through the index.php that's located on the public folder.

Answer (score 0):

How about simply using this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html/project/public/;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name domain.name;

    location /project-qa/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: When using this config I get a nginx 404 message.
I've looked into the error.log with debug on and this part looks pertinent for this:

2017/03/17 08:36:38 [debug] 16583#16583: *7 trying to use file: "/project-qa/index.php" "/var/www/html/project/public/project-qa/index.php"

2017/03/17 08:36:38 [debug] 16583#16583: *7 trying to use file: "=404" "/var/www/html/project/public=404"

Comment: Where is the `index.php` file then?

Comment: In the `/var/www/html/project/public/` folder.

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect new information.

Comment: Hey, thanks, tried that but that gives me the `twig_error_runtime` error again. One thing that worked, but it's not ideal, was leaving the `try_files $uri $uri/ /project-qa/index.php;`, and moving the `index.php` file from the `public` folder to `public/project-qa/`, and then adding a `../` to the craft path config in the `index.php` file. But it's not ideal, since it will need to be a folder there, named for every server type folder (live, staging, etc). But it might help understanding what might be causing it.